# Matplotlib Latex does not show custom box around word

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to get any solution from this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36401/drawing-boxes-around-words) to work via matplotlib. They all work in my latex editor but not in matplotlib. Here is one of the implementations in latex and matplotlib and their corresponding outputs.

Minimal Latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{on line, size=tight, colback=blue!40, #1}

\begin{document}
this is some \mybox{text} text
\end{document}
```

which will produce the result that I want (box around a word):
[latex showing custom box around word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1NNh.png)

Same code in matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib
preamble = [r"\usepackage{tcolorbox}",
            r"\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{on line, size=tight, colback=blue!40, #1}"]
params = {'text.usetex': True,
          'text.latex.preamble': preamble}
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)
matplotlib.pyplot.text(0.5, 0.5, r"this is some \mybox{text} text")
```

which will not show the box but just the text:
[matplotlib not showing the custom word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhWPZ.png)

Unfortunately matplotlib seems to ignore the box when putting it on the plot. Does anybody know a solution?